# Sharing session with ASP.NET site

Tags: sessions

My organization has a site built on ASP.NET. It uses ASP.NET to manage the users (students, class coordinators, and finances). However there is a small 'content' component of the site: about the class, about the organization, and some other content that will need to change and grow over time. However that part of the site is currently managed by Kintera which is $$. We want to get everything out of Kintera and into a CMS. ExpressionEngine is one being considered.

The site uses some iFrame's to pull content from the ASP.NET site into the Kintera managed content. This will likely be needed in an ExpressionEngine managed site.

These iFrames use content that is dynamically created from the ASP.NET site. The user's session will then need to be shared between ExpressionEngine and ASP.NET.

I am not involved in the ASP.NET site so can't say too much more than this. I will see if the developer of that site can provide any additional information or respond to your comments/answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However much I love ExpressionEngine would this not be a good case for using a .NET based CMS which could more easily integrate with your existing applications?

Something like Umbraco perhaps? Other Open Source .NET based CMS are available and if you are happy to pay a small licence fee similar to EE then I'm sure there will be even more options.

Sometimes you've got to take a step back and look at what is going to be easiest in the long-run. In this case, since you have an existing system built with .NET it makes little sense, to me, to shoehorn a completely different platform into the mix. If it's easy then fair enough but will there be further complications down the line when someone suggests integrating feature X or system Y?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this -- the answer provides a few solutions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544389/how-to-share-sessions-between-php-and-asp-net-application